# Произвольный порядок сортировки символов из константы в pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

На входе подается строка с произвольным набором символов, включающих в себя английские, русские строчные и заглавные буквы и цифры. Я записываю в секции `DECLARE` вот так:

```
DECLARE
  str CONSTANT varchar2(32767) := 'CBEdfa092борДЖЭ';
```

После сортировки первыми должны быть сначала строчные русские буквы, потом заглавные русские, цифры, английские строчные, английские заглавные.

Пример вывода по передаваемой константе: `борДЖЭ029adfBCE`.

Можно ли сделать сортировку, использую какую-либо готовую функцию, где можно будет передать шаблон и она по нему отсортирует(что-то наподобие формата для дат)?

Пишу анонимный блок в SQL Developer

Comment: Константа с символами задается вот так: `DECLARE str CONSTANT varchar2(32767) := 'CBEdfa092борДЖЭ';`. Мне ее нужно отсортировать по шаблону "яЯ, 0..9, zZ" в анонимном блоке.

Comment: вы бы показали пример входных данных и результата, который хотите увидеть

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас обновлю вопрос.

Comment: Похоже, что готовой функции у Оракла для этого нет. Кажется, что задачу можно решить через рекурсию или деревья.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with TRANS(start_, end_, ord) as(
 select 'a', 'z',1 from DUAL union all
 select 'A', 'Z',2 from DUAL union all
 select '0', '9',3 from DUAL union all
 select 'А', 'Я',4 from DUAL union all
 select 'Ё', 'Ё',4 from DUAL union all
 select 'а', 'я',5 from DUAL union all
 select 'ё', 'ё',5 from DUAL
), Src(str) as(
 select 'CBEdfa092борДЖЭёе' from DUAL
)
select listagg(ch) within group (order by rn)
  from (
    select ch, row_number() over(order by ord, ch) rn
      from ( select substr(str,level,1) ch
               from Src
            connect by substr(str,level,1) is not null
           ) left join TRANS on ch between start_ and end_
     order by ord, ch
  )
```

Остается только в Src подставить переменную с входной строкой, добавить into что бы поместить результат так же в переменную. И в таблице TRANS задать нужные приоритеты для диапазонов символов.

P.S. дополнительный уровень с нумерацией и использованию в listagg номера сделан из за того, что listagg не соблюдает нормальный, алфавитный порядок сортировки буквы `ё` (в отличие от обычного order by).

P.P.S. **Внимание** Выяснено экспериментальным путем (совместно с @Dmitry), что в зависимости от региональных настроек (видимо) правильный порядок буквы `ё` может быть правильным либо у listagg, либо у order by. Поэтому требуется проверка работы этих букв на целевой системе и применение в listagg сортировки либо в `rn`, либо по `ord, ch` в зависимости от того, что даст лучший результат.

Comment: Пожалуй Ваш ответ наиболее полно подходит для решения задачи. Спасибо, снова, @Mike :). И всем спасибо за столько решений(будет что на досуге поразбирать).

Comment: `select listagg(ch) within group (order by rn)` выводит правильно

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял вашу мысль, можно сделать как-то так. Допустим, есть источник:

```
with source as (
    select 'abc' a from dual union all
    select 'def' a from dual union all
    select 'hij' a from dual)
select *
  from source;
```

Надо сделать кастомную сотрировку, чтобы буква `d` шла первой, а `a` - второй. Тогда:

```
with source as (
    select 'abc' a from dual union all
    select 'def' a from dual union all
    select 'hij' a from dual)
select a, sort_column
  from (select a, translate(a, 'adh', 'dah') sort_column
          from source)
 order by sort_column;
```

С помощью `translate` заменяем символы, третий параметр задает необходимую сортировку. Далее сортируем по результату транслейта. Результат:

```
A   SORT_COLUMN
--- -----------
def aef         
abc dbc         
hij hij
```

**UPD.**
Немного о принципе формирования строки для функции `translate`. У оракла есть какая-то встроенная последовательность. В данном случае сортируется просто по возрастанию ASCII кодов. В функцию `translate` мы передаем первым параметром исходную строку, вторым - существующий порядок сортировки, третьим - преобразование к желаемому порядку. Тут можно сломать мозг, так что осторожнее.
Ваша исходная строка, существующий порядок сортировки, строка преобразования:

```
0 2 9 B C E a d f Д Ж Э б о р
б о р Д Ж Э 0 2 9 a d f B C E
a d f б о р Д Ж Э B C E 0 2 9 <-- это пойдет в функцию translate
```

Вам надо, чтобы сначала шла буква `б`, потом `о`, потом `р` и так далее. В существующем порядке сортировки первым идет `0` (вторая строка). Следовательно, под `б` в первой строке пишем 0 в третьей. Потом `о` - под `о` пишем `2`, и так далее. Для полного алфавита, соответственно, будет:

```
существующий порядок 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C ... a b c ... А Б В ... a б в ... э ю я
строка замены        а б в г д е ё ж з и к л м ................................. X Y Z
```

Принцип, надеюсь, понятен.

Далее все решается в один запрос:

```
select listagg(letters) within group (order by srt) 
  from (select letters, translate(letters, '029BCEadfДЖЭбор' /*существующий порядок*/, 
                                           'adfборДЖЭBCE029' /*строка замены*/) srt
          from (select substr('CBEdfa092борДЖЭ', level, 1) letters 
                  from dual connect by level <= length('CBEdfa092борДЖЭ'))
  )

RES 
----------------
борДЖЭ029adfBCE
```

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, посмотрите. Боюсь это решение не подходит

Comment: @Fasta Подходит, но его надо доработать напильником. Точнее, более детально объяснить, как именно оно работает. Минут через 20 допишу

Comment: Сначала разделил строку через `APEX_STRING.SPLIT()` и отсортировал пузырьком. Думал раскидать по массивам отдельно символы и цифры и потом уже собрать строку в нужном порядке. Но показалось это слишком недалеким решением и вот решил спросить, есть ли готовая функция в pl/sql для таких случаев :)

Comment: В курсе про `ё`, поэтому и отбросил эту затею с пузырьком и начал спрашивать здесь.

Comment: @Fasta Держите, написал.

Comment: @Mike Да, интересно. Только у меня наоборот почему-то... `listagg` в моем запросе ставит `ё` куда надо, а просто сортировка по `order by` ставит ее в конец

Comment: @Dmitry Вот это новость ... что то у оракла не так с этой функцией и видимо с региональными настройками. Значит решение lDrakonl самое близкое к истине, оно заведомо поставит символы туда, где они в таблице :)

Comment: @Mike Честно говоря, настолько глубоко не копал. У меня вообще `select ascii('ё') from dual;` возвращает 53649, а не сто с чем-то, как я привык. Я так понимаю, чтобы сделать платформо-и-чего-там-есть-еще-независимое решение, надо копнуть несколько глубже.

Comment: @Mike Скопировал, увидел.

Comment: @Mike Все нормально, она и у меня непойми какая: `select dump('й') from DUAL; Typ=96 Len=4: 208,184,204,134`

Comment: @Mike Да, substr воспринимает ее как два символа. Впрочем, как-то так и должно быть, по-моему.

Comment: @Dmitry В принципе да, в большинстве языков нормализации юникода по умолчанию не происходит и с ней проблемы будут. и ее просто так с клавиатуры не введешь (разве что в некоторых редакторах под mac os). P.S. Думаю лишние коменты можно почистить

Answer (score 3):

Написал запрос использующий рекурсивный with. Никаких дополнительных таблиц не надо. Можно просто передать строку и шаблон. Шаблон сортировки должен содержать все символы, которые могут встретится в сортируемой строке.
У запроса 2 параметра: `:str` - сортируемая строка, `:mask` - шаблон сортировки.

```
with src(symbol, tail, lvl) as( -- разобьем строку на символы
  select substr(:str, 1, 1) as symbol, 
         substr(:str, 2) as tail, 
         1 as lvl 
  from   dual
  union  all
  select substr(tail, 1, 1), 
         substr(tail, 2) as tail, 
         lvl + 1 as lvl 
  from   src
  where  length(tail) > 0
)
,mask(symbol, tail, lvl) as( -- разобьем маску на символы.
  select substr(:mask, 1, 1) as symbol, 
         substr(:mask, 2) as tail, 
         1 as lvl 
  from   dual
  union  all
  select substr(tail, 1, 1), 
         substr(tail, 2) as tail, 
         lvl + 1 as lvl 
  from   mask
  where  length(tail) > 0
)
select listagg(symbol) within group (order by lvl) 
from   (
       select m.symbol, m.lvl
       from   mask m 
       inner  join src s
       on     m.symbol = s.symbol
)
```

На вход для сортировки подал строку -`CBEdfa092борДЖЕ`, шаблон сортировки - `абвгдорАБВГД0123456789abcdefABCDEF`
результат:

> борДЖЕ029adfBCE

Сначала сортируемая строка и шаблон разбиваются на символы. При этом символы нумеруются и для каждого символа шаблона понятен его порядковый номер. После символы соединяются и сортируются по порядку шедшему в шаблоне с последующим объединением в одну строку.

Comment: Однако ваш подход оказался самым устойчивым к привратностям обычного order by с буквами `ё`, где напишешь, там и получишь и задумываться не надо :)

Comment: Однако в моем подходе не получится указывать диапазонами как у вас и всю строку сортировки надо прописать явно :)

Comment: Ну это да, я вообще очень ленив, могу два часа алгоритм изобретать, который избавит меня от 2х минутной, рутинной работы :) Кстати, только что хотел посмотреть как oracle справится с "й" (не путать с "й" :)) оказалось, что переживать о том, что он неверно ее отсортирует и вообще разобьет на части не приходится, мне не удалось ее вбить в редактор в виде `select 'й' from DUAL` и получить в первозданном виде :) (предложение надо копировать, в нем двух-кодовая й)