# Сортировка значений

Tags: sql, сортировка

У меня есть значения в БД:

```
 'б а в г'
```

Когда я делаю сортировку по алфавиту, в итоге у меня получается:

```
 'а б в г'
```

но как мне в один запрос сделать, чтобы у меня буква `'а'` стала последней,
то есть так:

```
 'б в г а'
```

Comment: у вас в sql такое работает `order by field='a',field`

Comment: вопросительный знак забыл :) ^ это был вопрос

Comment: странное желание... интерес чисто академический или есть какая-то более жизненная задача? сдаётся мне, средствами чистого SQL, в один запрос (без UNION'а) этого не сделать...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Произвольный порядок сортировки символов из константы в pl/sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747607/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-pl-sql)